# Power bi custom visual - Blank after cloning from GitHub Repo

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, pbiviz

I am trying to clone a GitHub Repo to local VS Code and adding other attributes to the existing project. I followed the following steps:

git:clone https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-visuals-gantt.git in VS Code(use Gantt as example)

npm install

pbiviz start

And there is an error below saying missing a file, I didn't find that file so I deleted the line in pbiviz.json refering to that.

After deleting that, I can run pbiviz start with no errors, but the visual stays blank even I put data in that. I wonder which step I did was wrong.

Anyone has the idea what happened? I would really appreciate your opinions:)

[pbiviz start error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWrbG.png)

[deleted the dependencies line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on5zc.png)

[No error after deleting that line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOJs9.png)

[blank visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eijDk.png)

Comment: I think I narrow the problem down to the API version, the API version of gantt chart in GitHub is 1.13.0, all other repos with API Version > 2.0.0 can be run correctly.

Comment: So does anyone know if it's possible to update the API Version of an existing custom visual?

Comment: Try to open https://localhost:8080/assets/status on browser. Probably you will see that browser blocked the request. You need to click to "Advanced"  > "Proceed" to allow the request to dev server.